# TFTP source code examples

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

Could someone point me to the source code for an ideally multi-threaded C++ TFTP application.  Even better if it's written using boost asio.

Just wanting to get an idea of how to structure a multi-threaded c++ network app with UDP rather than TCP.

I'll choose the answer based on how readable the code is and being in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open TFTP Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tftp-server/) Not purely C++ but a combination of C and C++

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of projects using Asio here: [who is using Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/WhoIsUsingAsio)